# php54 not recognizing php code in file with html extension

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, homebrew, php5

For example, echo phpinfo() returns nothing in my .html file

but index.php returns with the info

wich setting needs to be adjusted?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Apache to look for PHP in html files.

You can use either [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype), or [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch), e.g.:

```
<FilesMatch \.html$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Note this could impact performance, as each HTML file will now be checked for PHP code.

FilesMatch is better then AddType as it'll protect you from some exploits.  Details about this can be seen in [step 6 of the php install manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)

Comment: thanks, I was surprised it did not work because on my hosting-provider it's not a problem

Answer (score 1):

you can not execute php code in an HTML file, the file needs to be a PHP file with an extension of .php or .php5

In order to execute PHP code inside HTML you will need to add a handler

Enter this in the `.htaccess` file in the root of your Apache web server

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

If you're running PHP as CGI:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```